# Как в ReactJS взаимодействовать с props, которые были указаны при рендере компонента?

Tags: reactjs, click, state

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: в ReactJS у меня есть компонент `Food`, который по сути представляет собой товар в корзине интернет-магазина. Есть некая цена и поле `input`, в котором уазывается количество единиц данного товара (по умолчанию, стоит "1").

```
class Food extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { prop: 1 }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="count">
          <p>Количество</p>
          <button onClick={this.less}>-</button>
          <input value={this.state.prop} />
          <button onClick={this.more}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div className="price">
          <span>{this.props.price}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

При рендере компонента в `this.props.price` указывается стоимость товара:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Food price="20999" />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Как можно реализовать функцию увеличения или уменьшения стоимости товара, при изменении его количества в поле `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто изменяете стейт. Я Ваш `state.prop` заменил на `state.count`, добавил методы `less` и `more` изменения этого состояния, а также метод `sum`, для подсчета суммы в зависимости от количества (можно и без метода, но лучше с ним - дает возможность легкой манипуляции с данными)

```
class Food extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      count: 1,
    }

    this.less = this.less.bind(this)
    this.more = this.more.bind(this)
    this.sum = this.sum.bind(this)
  }

  less() {
    this.setState(({count}) => ({count: count > 1 ? count - 1 : count}));
  }

  more() {
    this.setState(({count}) => ({count: count + 1}));
  }

  sum() {
    return this.props.price * this.state.count
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="count">
          <p>Количество</p>
          <button onClick={this.less}>-</button>
          <input value={this.state.count} />
          <button onClick={this.more}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div className="price">
          <span>{this.sum()}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!